# Predicting the item to sell, given a list of items

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, apriori

We have the data set which contains the mapping of customer to the product he buy like

```
c1->{P1, P2, p5} 
c2->{P3, P5, p4} 
c3->{P5, P2, p3}
....
```

on that basis we need to recommend a product for the customer,

let say for cx customer we need to recommend the product, since we have the data what cx is buying from the above set, and we run apriori to figure out the recommendation, but for big data set it's very slow ?

can someone please give us some suggestion by which we can crack that problem ?

Comment: I don't completely understand what your training data is. Could you throw some light on that? If you have a list of all sales by "similar" merchants over a period of time, and need to find items that people buy together, try googling for "Frequent Itemset Mining" or "Market Basket Analysis".

Answer (score 0):

I assume the items merchant is selling is your training data and then a random item is your testing data. So the most probable item to sell will depend upon the "features" of the items which merchant is selling currently. "Features" mean the price of the item, category, these are the details you will have. Then to decide the algorithm, I recommend you to have a look at the feature space. If there are small clusters, then even nearest-neighbor search would work better. If the distribution is complex then you can go for SVM. There are various data visualization techniques. Taking PCA and taking visualizing first two dimensions can be a good choice.